# okta integration with Azure ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, okta

I am new to Azure as well as okta and now I am trying to configure okta users with Azure ad ,
I had created an application under enterprises application in Azure ad and provide access to all users in azure ad, now I want to provide access to one of my partner who uses okta but not azure ad now have to proved access to okta users to access my application which is in Azure ad.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little vague, but it sounds like you need to create a guest profile in Azure AD, locked down with RBAC (Very Important), to allow access specifically to your App. Imho you should let your partner worry about configuring their own Okta application, since you're basically working as their IT team if you start going into their Okta account to make changes. Also, if you break something, it's now your companies problem.